# Twitter Bootstrap : Input width changes when button is added

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an input box styled using Bootstrap. The width of the input box changes when I remove the button from the input-group. How can I have full width without using input box?

With Button

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <input class="form-control" name="abc" placeholder="1" type="text">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Without Button

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <input class="form-control" name="abc" placeholder="2" type="text">
</div>
```

The width of input box changes when a button is added

http://jsfiddle.net/hq5A8/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't plan to use a button next to it, it's not an input group. Remove the surrounding `<div class='input-group'>` and you should be fine.

Your new code without the button will be simply:

```
<input class="form-control" name="abc" placeholder="2" type="text">
```

In case you want a wrapper, you should use the class `form-group` on the wrapper div instead.

Comment: What's the scenario where you prefer one over other, between `form-group` & `input-group`? `input-group` lets me suffix `-sm` to make it small. But I can't achieve the same with `form-group`?

Comment: If you're using bootstrap 3, the form-group is just a wrapper to define one row of form elements in case you'll be using labels for eg. horisontal forms. The input group allows you to put multiple input-related elements on the same line, but does not consider the label. Check out the documentation: [Bootstrap 3 official page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)